# External IP is not accessible outside the function in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ip

I am new here. I am trying to get external IP using a package named "external-ip" They have this code in their example

```
const getIP = require('external-ip')(); 
getIP((err, ip) => {
          if (err) {
              // every service in the list has failed
              throw err;
          }
          ip = ip;
          console.log(ip);
});
```

It is working perfectly however I want to use IP outside the function may I know how can I use it ?

I tried this but didnt work for me

```
const ipaddress = getIP((err, ip) => {
          if (err) {
              // every service in the list has failed
              throw err;
          }
          return ip;
          console.log(ip);
});

console.log(ipaddress);
```

Comment: define your ip variable with 'let', and do it outside your function

Comment: Worked! Thanks. If I may ask what if I return the ip? Will it stored in ipaddress variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First define `ip` with let

`ip` is defined under the local scope of your program which means it is only accessible within your function. Now you should avoid using global scope as much as possible as that is generally considered bad practice but that is one way to have the `ip` varaible accessible from anywhere in your program. The other way would be to return it

```
const getIP = require('external-ip')(); 
const ipaddress = getIP((err, ip) => {
          if (err) {
              // every service in the list has failed
              throw err;
          }
          console.log(ip);
          return ip;
});

let ip = ipaddress()
console.log(ip)
```

Note that anything after the return statement is a dead code and will not run so any code you want to run should be placed before any return statement(notice the position of the console.log() in the function

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
let ipaddress;
getIP((err, ip) => {
          if (err) {
              // every service in the list has failed
              throw err;
          }
          ipaddress = ip;
});

console.log(ipaddress);
```

Solution by Edgar Cuarezma

Comment: avoid using global variables as much as possible, they are bad practice and if you are going to use a global variable in javascript in should be immutable which means you should make use of `const` instead of `let`